# Meteor - Browser unresponsive after logging in

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

So far I've been using accounts-ui and {{> loginButtons}} for my app, and everything was fine. I recently implemented my own signup/login so I could have my own customization, and everything is working (I am able to sign up, create a new account, and log in with that new account).

The problem is that after signing up or logging in with my custom login, any template that gets rendered, freezes (can't scroll up/down). I have to refresh the page for it to work (the template needs to be created again). So I have a hack in my `Meteor.loginWithPassword` callback to reload the page after the user logs in with no errors. This definitely is not the Meteor way, and gives the user a bad experience. So I would definitely like to avoid this. But I can't seem to find the solution.

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function(error) {
            if (error) {
                alert('Invalid credentials - please check your email/password and try again');  
            } else {
                Meteor._reload.reload()
            }
});
```

I have a setting in my Iron Router that says: "if the user is not logged in, render the landing page, and if the uses is logged in, proceed to the next action". Could it be something here?

```
var requireLogin = function() {
    if (! Meteor.user()) {
        if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
            this.render('loading');
        } else {
            this.render('landingpage');
        }
    } else {
        this.next();
    }
}

Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {except: 'landingpage'});
```

Or am I supposed to be doing something more in the `Meteor.loginWithPassword()` callback function?

I've spent about 30 hours on this and decided it's probably best to ask for help instead of wasting more time and getting no results. (Learned a lot about Iron Router and accounts in the process though - so that's a plus).

Any help/new perspective is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

**THIS IS NOT AN ISSUE ANYMORE**
Through several more hours of logic and reasoning, (who am I kidding, it was all trial and error), I got it to work by placing the login template in the main layout instead of the landing page. Once the user logs in, Meteor effectively destroys the landing page template, taking my login template down with it. My guess is that this was causing my Meteor.loginWithPassword() callback to not fire properly. Oh well, that's a few hours I won't be getting back.

**Thanks for those who took the time to view the question**

Comment: Why do you run `Meteor._reload.reload()` (this is meant for reloading the page after a hot code reload)?

Comment: @Akshat hes runnign `Meteor._reload.reload()`, because when the users login the screens freezes for some reason, so he need to manually reloads the page.

Comment: Does this help (stop the freezing)? Also could you provide what route this happens on and an example of your page route, the `landingpage` for example?

Comment: @Akshat @Ethaan is right. I have to do `Meteor._reload.reload()` to reload the page so it unfreezes and becomes scrollable again. This basically happens on any route where the user logs in (ie: `http://myapp.com/<anyroute>` which requires that the user is logged in). `landingpage` is just the name of a template which I display if the user is not logged in. I should also mention, that when I log the user out with `Meteor.logout()` this also happens (the page freezes) when the `landingpage` renders.

Comment: @Akshat Also, here is the route which I'm routing the user to after logging in:  `Router.route('/', { 
  name: 'home',
  waitOn: function() {
   return [
     Meteor.subscribe('sub1'),
     Meteor.subscribe('sub2'),
     Meteor.subscribe('sub3'),
     Meteor.subscribe('sub4')
     ];
  } 
 });`  - Sorry about the formatting. Hope that helps.

Comment: Figured it out, thanks for your help guys.